# Where can Global Maxima and Minima occur in a Bounded Region in multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, global-optimization

I was watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hg38kfK5w4E&ab_channel=TheOrganicChemistryTutor
about finding global max and min for a multivariable function.

He said that they occur at

at the corners of the rectangle , at some point along one of the borders, at the critical  "or some other point inside this region.

Are they all true? Someone in the comment pointed out that he made a mistake?

So in general, what types of points can potentially be global maxima or minima for a multivariable  function and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and if $f\colon S\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is a continuous map which is differentiable in the interior $\mathring S$ of $S$, then $f$ has a maximum and a minimum in $S$. Furthermore, the points at which the maximum and the minimum are attained must be located at the boundary $\partial S$ of $S$ or at the critical points of $f$ in $\mathring S$.

If $S$ is closed but unbounded, then $f$ can fail to have a maximum or a minimum, but it is still true that, if it has, then they are attained at the boundary $\partial S$ of $S$ or at the critical points of $f$ in $\mathring S$.

Comment: Thank you Dr Santos, so he is wrong and the global extrema cannot happen in the interior of the square/region?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. Just consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ in a square centered at $(0,0)$. Clearly, the minimum is attained at $(0,0)$.